# Android replacement for requestLegacyExternalStorage?

Tags: android, svg, google-play

I have an application published in Google play store, its name is PainterSVG, main purpose is to help SVG designers to create/edit SVG vector images.

It works well when user opens external SVG files, edit, and save back to external storage, using requestLegacyExternalStorage flag in AndroidManifest file.

But now Google is saying writing to external storage is only allowed for File Manager applications. And my app is not File Manager and will be delisted from play store, if I continue to use this flag.

What is the best solution for this case? I can share SVG files out from app with FileProvider, but users are complaining it is very inconvenient, as they have to share to something like email and receive the file in email.

Is there a better solution for this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can let the user pick files with Storage Access Framework and also save files in directories picked with Storage Acces Framework. We dont know you app so you could better explain what your app does with files now.

Comment: Further on Android 11 devices you can save files produced bu your app in for instance a subdirectory of public Documents directory in the old way. So `Google is saying writing to external storage is only allowed for File Manager applications.` is not true. Maybe it's not allopwed but possible it is.

Comment: `will be delisted from play store, if I continue to use this flag.` What i read is that that flag is neglected.  Anyhow it would only have effect on Android 10 devices.